# c# program to control and arduino rc car

Tags: c#, serial-port

so I have made a c# program to control my RC car through a serial port and when I press the button to make the car move forward it keeps going when I un press the button. So in short I want to control the buttons with the arrow keys and when I press the key it should go forward then when I let it go it should stop. Thanks in advance for your help. And you can probably tell I am a newbie.

picture of program:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV8wa.jpg

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace CSharpEasySerial
{
    public partial class frmSerial : Form
    {

    public static System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort1;
    private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line);

    public frmSerial()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components); // Creating the new object.
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM" + numCom.Value.ToString(); // Setting what port number.
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600; // Setting baudrate.
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true; // Enable the Data Terminal Ready 
            serialPort1.Open(); // Open the port for use.
            btnConnect.Text = "Connected.";
            btnConnect.Enabled = false;
            numCom.Enabled = false;
            serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x08 }, 0, 1);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Found. Try Again","Error");
        }
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Sends the text as a byte.
        serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(txtDatasend.Text) }, 0, 1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x00 }, 0, 1);
        serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x02 }, 0, 1);
    }
```

Comment: You don't have a "button_unclick".  Meaning... you never unset the serial port value that makes the car go forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a "Button_Unclick" event to send the stop command to your serial port.

You don't say what your form technology is...  however in wpf this might take the form of...

```
private void button1_OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     // whatever command it is to stop... your the expert here...
     serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x08 }, 0, 1);
}
```

**Update:** So for the keys here is what you need on your form... is it winforms?  WPF?   Here is the winforms app I tested it in (because that's what I had open at the moment)  :)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += form_KeyDown;
    this.KeyUp += form_KeyUp;
}

private void form_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"KeyUp:"+ e.KeyValue);
    // user released the key so send whatever you need to stop...
}

private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"KeyDown:"+ e.KeyValue);
    // user pressed the key so send whatever you need to make it go..
}
```

**Update 2:** Here are the methods / setup for WPF

In your window.xaml...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        KeyDown="MainWindow_OnKeyDown"
        KeyUp="MainWindow_OnKeyUp"
        >
```

In your xaml.cs...

```
private void MainWindow_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
}

private void MainWindow_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
}
```

**Update 2:** Here is the switch statement that will check the key values..

```
private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
            // do your up arrow thing here...
            break;
        case Keys.Down:
            if (e.Control)
            {
                // get fancy if the control key + down arrow is pressed 
                // at the same time
            }
            else
            {
                // do the normal down arrow stuff
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey kevin thanks for the reply... this didn't quite work... ok do u know how I could do this with the arrow keys? like as long as im pressing it down it will lets say go forward, but as soon as I lift up my finger from the up arrow it will stop ( do a new event)

Comment: how do I fugure out what form type it is (im a newbee)

Comment: Does your form inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`?  It will look something like this if it does.. `public partial class MyFormName : Form`

Comment: It says public partial class frmSerial : Form @kevin

Comment: Yep that's WinForms.   The first example above should be what you need.  Let me know if it works.  You will also need to check the `KeyPressed` event for what key was pressed... but I didn't include that logic since you'll likely be looking for multiple keys and doing various things.

Comment: thanks kevin that worked but I want to customize the code for each key ie: forward, backward, left, right

Comment: Just added a switch statement example to check for different keys.

Comment: im a newb so I hv no idea how to do that can u pls give me an example efor one case for example the up arrow